# Solution to $y'' - 2y = 2\tan^3x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm struggling with this nonhomogeneous second order differential equation

$$y'' - 2y = 2\tan^3x$$

I assumed that the form of the solution would be $A\tan^3x$ where A was some constant, but this results in a mess when solving. The back of the book reports that the solution is simply $y(x) = \tan x$.

Can someone explain why they chose the form $A\tan x$ instead of $A\tan^3x$?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Assume the particular solution is of the form $a \tan x$ and solve for the constant.

If we do that, we get:

$$2 a \tan x \sec^2 x - 2a \tan x = 2 \tan^3 x$$

What do you get when you simply that expression?

$$2 a \tan x (\sec^2 x - 1) = 2 \tan^3 x$$

$$2 a \tan x(\tan^2 x) = 2 \tan^3 x$$

Thus, $a = 1$

Now write the solution as:

$$y = y_h + y_p = c_1 e^{\sqrt{2} x}+c_2 e^{-\sqrt{2} x} + \tan x$$

I assumed you knew how to find $y_h$, but if not, give a yell.

Note: there are other approaches we can use to not guess, but maybe you haven't learned those yet (Variation of parameters, Green's Functions, Series Solutions...).

**Update**

By the way, try this same problem if the result was $\tan x$ or $\tan^2 x$. In other words, the $\tan^3 x$ is a somewhat contrived example.

Comment: I get that it works, I'm just curious why. Is there some rule that you always use the first power of tan when solving?

Comment: I've never seem anything like this before using the method of judicious guessing.

Comment: Often times, guessing at the particular solution is the first approach. When using trig forms, strange things can happen. Some books even call it judicious guessing! Regards

Comment: So it seems. Hmmm. Well I appreciate the very thorough response! (And I do know how to get the homogeneous part.) Thanks!

Comment: @codedude: See my additional note at the end and I can add one of those if you wish to see it, but it may just confuse you. Regards

Comment: yeah, we haven't gone through any of those yet so it probably wouldn't help too much but thanks anyways!

Comment: Nice work, Amzoti, as is usual!

Comment: Indeed, TGIF!!!

Answer (score 2):

Have you learned variation of parameters? This is a method, rather than lucky guessing :)
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters

Comment: Nope. My teacher apparently thought we could skip that...crap.

Comment: Well, I remember it from TAing differential equations my first year in grad school. So, if you're wanting to actually solve inhomogeneous ODEs, it's worth learning :)